# Создать строку определенного вида PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста!
В общем я получаю через mysql запрос сперва количество элементов например результат 8 при помощи запроса

```
SELECT count(episode_num) AS counterContent FROM episode
```

На выходе мне нужно при помощи PHP/MySQL получить строку при результате запроса = 8 строку такого вида `a:8:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;i:7;i:8;}`
Если результат запроса count 2 то соответственно такого вида.

```
a:2:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php), которая сгенерирует вам из массива

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

строку

```
a:8:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;i:7;i:8;}
```

Код для проверки

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$str = serialize($arr);
print_r ($str);
```